# Where to store custom icons in Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, icons

I am creating my own icons for buttons. I did some snooping around, and it looks like application icons usually go under:

ApplicationName/Contents/Resources/some.png

What do I do to recreate my own structure like this for icons? I don't see any "Content/Resources" in Project navigator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode will move the icons to the `Resources` folder in your app package automatically during a build.

Just add the icon files to your Xcode project and it will detect that they are image resource files and add them to the Copy Bundle Resources build phase for you. Any files that are included in the Copy Bundle Resources build phase will be copied to the `Resources` folder in the built app's bundle.

It doesn't matter which group you put the images into in the Xcode files list because the file group organisation is ignored in the built product, so feel free to put them where you like. I often create a `Media` group with subgroups such as `Images` and `Audio` but it's completely up to you.